# CSV.File ignores options

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, julia

I have a problem with pandas in julia. Look at this code. I'm trying to read a csv and convert it to a pandas dataframe. But the header was not accepted. Okay, so I google the options and set header to 1. But it does not work. Also I set the Datatypes manual, because the frist two should be a Float64 and the last should be a Int. I got no error message, but if I set the types manual, all the colums are floats. Thats not what I want to set. Maybe ists a mistake from a julia beginner.

```
 julia> using Pandas
 
 julia> using CSV
 
 julia> ofenbelegung_df = CSV.File("dichte.csv"; header=1,types=[Float64, Float64, Int]) |> DataFrame
          0       1    2
 0     20.0  7863.0  1.0
 1    100.0  7834.0  1.0
 2    200.0  7803.0  1.0
 3    300.0  7770.0  1.0
 4    400.0  7736.0  1.0
 
 
 julia> ofenbelegung_df = CSV.File("dichte.csv"; types=[Float64, Float64, Int]) |> DataFrame
          0       1    2
 0     20.0  7863.0  1.0
 1    100.0  7834.0  1.0
 2    200.0  7803.0  1.0
 3    300.0  7770.0  1.0
 4    400.0  7736.0  1.0
 
 
 julia> ofenbelegung_df = CSV.File("dichte.csv") |> DataFrame
        0     1  2
 0     20  7863  1
 1    100  7834  1
 2    200  7803  1
 3    300  7770  1
 4    400  7736  1
 
 julia>
```

original csv file

```
Temp;Val;Gr
20;7863;1
100;7834;1
200;7803;1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems are with Pandas.jl not with CSV.jl (in particular `header=1` is the default value so passing it this way has no effect)

Here is an example

```
julia> using CSV, Pandas, Tables

julia> file = IOBuffer("""Temp;Val;Gr
       20;7863;1
       100;7834;1
       200;7803;1""")
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=false, seekable=true, append=false, size=43, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> CSV.File(file, types=[Float64, Float64, Int]) |> DataFrame
       0       1    2
0   20.0  7863.0  1.0
1  100.0  7834.0  1.0
2  200.0  7803.0  1.0


julia> CSV.File(file, types=[Float64, Float64, Int]) |> columntable
(Temp = [20.0, 100.0, 200.0], Val = [7863.0, 7834.0, 7803.0], Gr = [1, 1, 1])
```

a work-around for Pandas.jl is:

```
julia> CSV.File(file, types=[Float64, Float64, Int]) |> columntable |> pairs |> DataFrame
    Temp     Val  Gr
0   20.0  7863.0   1
1  100.0  7834.0   1
2  200.0  7803.0   1
```

Note that if you used DataFrames.jl instead of Pandas.jl all is correct:

```
julia> using CSV, DataFrames

julia> file = IOBuffer("""Temp;Val;Gr
       20;7863;1
       100;7834;1
       200;7803;1""")
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=false, seekable=true, append=false, size=43, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> CSV.File(file, types=[Float64, Float64, Int]) |> DataFrame
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Temp     Val      Gr    
     │ Float64  Float64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │    20.0   7863.0      1
   2 │   100.0   7834.0      1
   3 │   200.0   7803.0      1
```

(I am using a fresh Julia session due to name clashes between Pandas.jl and DataFrames.jl packages.

Comment: An alternative would be to use Pandas.read_csv() instead of CSV.jl.

But DataFrames.jl instead of Pandas is imho the better option.